# Recommended techniques for outputting a PDF eBook integrating data from a SQLite database?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, pdf, pdf-generation

We are getting a lot of requests for an eBook version of our database driven iOS application, and I am trying to figure out the easiest way to automate creating this as part of our XCode build process.

I'd like to find a way to generate a PDF eBook based upon some easily designed templates and the SQLite database that is at the heart of our app.

I am having a hard time find Mac-compatible tools that can do this, and I have no idea how to integrate this into our XCode build process.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Ideally I'd like to find something that will allow our designer to easily lay out the page templates with a GUI tool, and which I can then programmatically populate with the database contents, spitting out a PDF automatically with each new build of the application.

One suggestion I've heard is using LaTeX, but that seems to have a reputation for "being a nightmare" with tables, and we would want tables in our layout.  Also - I can't find a way to allow a designer to easily lay out the templates with LaTeX. Perhaps I am just looking in the wrong places for LaTeX resources and examples, so pointers here would be appreciated.

In the Window's world, I've heard Crystal Reports might do some of what I want.  But I want something that can integrate into my XCode build environment.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into LaTeX. It can generate high-quality PDFs from plain text (+ control codes) source files, which makes it ideal for building stuff on demand.

Comment: Looking into LaTeX, it seems as if layout and tables are regarded as a nightmare.  Our data is very tabular, and we are adding fields all the time. Is there a WYSWIG designer that can layout a LaTex template? I can't find one, but might be looking in the wrong places...

Comment: NO, it's not a wysiwyg type system. Tables aren't really bad, but you'll need a few optional packages... longtable, tabularx, others, mix to taste. There is lots of good doc out there on this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the general pointer towards LaTeX, it is giving me something to chew on. Links to documentation and examples would also be much appreciated - particularly things similar to what I am trying to do (SQLite, XCode, template based layout, PDF output, etc).  I have started doing some searches into how to do these things with LaTeX and have been overwhelmed by the seeming complexity.  I think I may be looking in the wrong places - there are a huge amount of very arcane resources out there.